# iptables: how do i allow all to connect at ssh except specific IP addresses?

Tags: iptables

Would like to ask if this is possible, allow all to my ssh except certain IPs.

Currently i got:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 123.45.67.89 --dport 22 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

I tested it with blocked IP, still going thru and can login. The sequence is correct isnt it?

Please no `ufw` solution, i want raw iptables. Thanks.

Comment: It seems ok, but you may have other rules that allow the traffic. Please post the complete firewall rules.

Comment: all good no @MichaelHampton, found the issue, you are right though, its to do with other rules. posted the rules below. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

ok. found the issue and resolved my problem. its to do with `MASQUERADE` so I commented it and works fine.

here's the code snip:

```
...

#  Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites and SSL).
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8081 -j DROP

# LOCAL NETWORK ACCESS
#/sbin/iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE <- cause
#/sbin/iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.9.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT #SSH LOCAL HOME

# BLOCK IPs
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 117.34.70.33 -j DROP

# Zeacurity rules
# {SSH_BLOCK_IPS}

#  Allow SSH connections
#
#  The -dport number should be the same port number you set in sshd_config
#
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

...

/sbin/iptables -nvL
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm doing this with the ufw firewall. I recommend you to try it quite simply and successfully.

ufw allow from 123.45.67.89 to any port 22

Comment: That's not what i am trying to achieve. I want everyone to connect to ssh EXCEPT to specific IPs.

Comment: Its the other way around from your solution.